# Can the Service search-bar be edited to search for results beyond salesforce?

Tags: lightning, service

In Lighting the Service search-bar (figure below) shows search results such as contacts, leads or opportunities. This results are in scoped within Salesforce.

I wonder if it's possible now or in the future to edit this feature to show results beyond Salesforce?

[image: Fig.01]

Comment: Probably, in some kind of future... SCNR

Comment: Thank you for the response. Do you know of a way/feature that would get me close to this goal?

Answer (score 1):

In Communities, you can use [forceCommunity:searchInterface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/forceCommunity:searchInterface/documentation) to build any sort of search, including making API calls, etc. There's a [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/communities_theme_layout/custom_search) that goes over this in great detail. Unfortunately, this means that your users would have to go over to a Community in order to use this component. We don't know when/if we'll get such a feature in Lightning itself, but I thought I'd bring this to your attention in case it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately we are trying to add this features into the specific search section.